# How to insert DateTime (or DateTime2) with Dapper?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, dapper, datetime2

I'm trying to do the following:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add(...);
p.Add(...);
// ideally I want to insert null for end date, but I also tried DateTime.MinValue
// or some other date, but doesn't help
p.Add("@endDate", null, DbType.DateTime, ParameterDirection.Input);
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    // stored procedure does 'select SCOPE_IDENTITY()' to return the id of inserted row.
    int id = con.Query<int>("StoredProcedureName", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
}
```

This is throwing "InvalidCastException" and I believe this is becase of the date. I previously had datetime2(20) for the endDate in the sql db, changed it to datetime to see if it fixes it, but doesn't. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invalid cast here is that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` actually returns `decimal`. The parameters are working fine.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. i did search for dapper related issues and found some discussion about SCOPE_IDENTITY(), but I didn't pay enough attention to realize that it is related to this issue.